# $replaceRoot of embedded document inside an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am fairly new to MongoDB and I came across the [$replaceRoot(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) which I need to output the document the way I need it.

**Document Schema**

```
{
name: "Apple",
image: "",
is_fruit: true,
other: [
  {
    url: "",
    quotes: { // saved as ObjectId and is then lookedup or populated
    text: "An apple a day keeps the doctor away"
  }
}
]
}
```

**Wanted Output**

```
{
  name: "Apple",
  image: "",
  is_fruit: true,
  other: [
    {
      text: "An apple a day keeps the doctor away"
    },
  ...
  ]
  }
```

i.e: To make quotes field as the root of the other array and not the root of entire document.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to limit the number of returned fields inside the array? Or where do the ´url´ and ´quotes´ field go to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) like for embedded array but you can achieve similar effect using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to transform the array into new format.

Something like

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "other": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$other",
          "as": "res",
          "in": {
            "text": "$$res.text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can easily do something similar in client side code.

Answer (score 0):

By using $replaceRoot(aggregation) here is the output.
P.S: The collection name I used is 'demoStack' replace it with your specific collections.

[image]

Query is :

```
db.demoStack.aggregate([
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ 
    {name:"$name"},
    { image: "$image" },
    {is_fruit:"$is_fruit"},
    {other:"$other.quotes"}        
    ] } } } ])
```